# Choosing random number $[1,n]$. What is the expected value of $f(x) = x^2$?

Tags: probability

We have just started learning discrete probability and this question came up:

> We choose a random number from $[1,n]$, and we let be $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = 2^{-x}$.
>
> I) What is the expected value of $f$?
>
> II) What is the expected value of $g$?
>
> II) What is the expected value of $f \circ g$?

Now I am very new to this, but, isn't expected value defined as $E[f] = \sum_{x \in \omega} {x \cdot Pr(x)}?$

Our $\omega$ here is $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and of size $n$ with each element of probability $Pr(x \in \omega ) = \frac{1}{n}$.

But then, what is the meaning of $f(x) = x^2$?

Comment: Is it a random integer, or a continuous random number?

Comment: a random integer... what was explained is what I wrote and nothing further.

Comment: The correct formula for the expected value is: $E[f(X)] = \sum_{x\in\omega} f(x)\cdot P(X=x)$. The formula you've written is $E[X]$.

Comment: Thank you. So how do we exactly calculate that?

Comment: Your notation is a bit odd.  I would call $X$ the random variable.  You are are asking for the expected values of $f(X)$, $g(X)$ and $f(g(X))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $E[f]=\sum_{x \in \omega} f(x)\cdot Pr(x)$.  So to find $E[f]$ you need $\sum_{i=1}^ni^2\frac 1n$ and similarly for $g$.

Comment: Thank you so much.
Now what about the composition of both of them? What is the concept behind that?

Comment: @TheNotMe:  You need to figure out what $f(g(x))$ is, and again plug it in.

Comment: is $f \circ g = f(g(x)) = \frac{1}{4^x}$ ? or is it $g(f(x))$?

Comment: Correct, $f\circ g (x)=f(g(x))=4^{-x}$

Comment: Thank you so, so much for your kind help and patience.